# Extracting last 10 lines of a file that match "foo"

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I want to write the last ten lines which contain a spesific word such as "foo" in a file to a new text file named for instance `boo.txt`.

How can I achieve this in the command prompt of a unix terminal?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use `grep` and `tail`:

```
grep "foo" input.txt | tail -n 10 > boo.txt
```

The default number of lines printed by `tail` is 10, so you can omit the `-n 10` part if you always want that many.

The `>` redirection will create `boo.txt` if it didn't exist. If it did exist prior to running this, the file will be truncated (i.e. emptied) first. So `boo.txt` will contain at most 10 lines of text in any case.

If you wanted to append to `boo.txt`, you should change the redirection to use `>>`.

```
grep "bar" input.txt | tail -n 42 >> boo.txt
```

You might also be interested in `head` if you are looking for the first occurrences of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep foo /path/to/input/file | tail > boo.txt
```